# Magento test installation redirects to production

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, http-redirect

I have a test environment for magento in a local VM. It is a copy of the production code and database. To get this working I do the following:

- In the mysql dump, I replace www.website.com with test.website.com for all domains.
- I change the hosts file in the VM and on my local machine to direct traffic to the vm for the test domains.
- In the index.php there is a condition for different store codes that is updated for the test subdomains.

This works for an old backup. When I backup a new production database and replace the subdomains, I can restore that database and that works. When I update the code, things go wrong. I open the page test.website.com, and at some point it gives a 302 code and redirects to www.website.com, the production site.

The VM is Ubuntu Desktop, so it has its own browser, and I could change the host file to keep the www-traffic local as well. I prefer to use the test domain however.

I would like to know how I can find out where the redirect happens. At some point it calls mage::run, and then I'm lost. Where can I look and how can I find this redirect?

Comment: Have you double checked if the table "core_config_data" table contains your localise settings for "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url" paths? Also, checking the .htaccess file would also be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. In both the core_config_data and htaccess I could find incorrect settings. I have fixed these, but still the redirect stays...

Comment: What happens if you put 0 on "web/url/redirect_to_base" in the table "core_config_data"?

Comment: And did you copy your cache to your local testing VM?

Comment: did you edit the database in the app/etc/local.xml?  <dbname><![CDATA[your_db_name]]></dbname>

Comment: @Dan, many thanks! If you want the points, make this an answer!

Comment: @gelleby, yes I copy the cache, and I clear the var/cache folder afterwards.

Comment: I configured the VM (not magento) to block outgoing mails, so I can test mails without confusing clients. I realise I should block outbound mysql connections as well in the firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My basic Magento 1.7.0.2 site copy:

1. Copy the db via sql
2. In the table "core_config_data edit the web/secure/base_url  and  web/unsecure/base_url
3. Copy the site files
4. Edit the database value in the app/etc/local.xml   `<dbname><![CDATA[your_db_name]]></dbname>`
5. Clean up the cache 
   var/cache/*  sometime var/locks/* var/session/*
6. Always check!

Comment: Thanks again! I use sed to search the mysql dump and replace the www-subdomain with the test-subdomain (for all domains). That should cover step 2. Cleaning up the logs, reports and old backups may speed up the file syncing. Afterwards I reset the rights of all folders and some files, and change the ownership to the apache user.

Comment: I like the sed use. Do you clean logs reports imports backups in production or as part of the dump?

Comment: I clean logs etc in production if it's OK to do so. The systemlog gets big over time, something I need to look into another time. I simply delete it and magento creates a new one by itself. If I really would need to have an old log I can always restore a backup.

Comment: The sed script I use: `sed -i.bak "s/www\.klmnop123/www.test.klmnop123/g;s/www\.abcdef567/www.test.abcdef567/g;s/www\.test./test./g" magentodump.sql`. It replaces `www.` with `www.test.`, and then `www.test.` with `test.`. I don't remember why I didn't replace www with test immediately, but it didn't work out otherwise. I create one script that does this for 10 domains at once and it takes 3 to 5 minutes for a 3GB mysql dump on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the app/local/config.xml (or around there, sorry its been a while, I think) or in the admin->configuration section that you can provide the Base URL, check to see if those are still set as the old value

Comment: That should be `app/etc/config.xml`. I don't see anything there. I can't open the admin because that redirects as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Of course you have to use the steps described by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107310/1767910). But that didn't help for me. The solution I've found was to change to apc (Alternative PHP Cache) settings (in /app/etc/local.xml):

```
<cache>
    <backend>apc</backend>
    <prefix>other_prefix_then_production_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing here, and where the file is located?

Comment: I've improved the answer. By changing the prefix, the apc doesn't use the cache as the production site, which can cause the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the steps described by Dan works, try deleting the content of the /tmp/magento/var/cache/ folder and rebooting the server.

```
rm -rf /tmp/magento/var/cache/*
```